# Setting a variable to System.in outside of the class

Tags: java, inputstream

I have only access to change code outside the class that this line of code was written:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Since the inputStreamReader constructor only accepts InputStreams, how do I set a variable inside of another class to reference an InputStream like *System.in*? Note: the variable '*in*' has not been declared yet if that helps.

```
class Prime {        
    void checkPrime(int... possi) {
        for(int item: possi) {
            for(int i =0; i<item; i++){
                if(i>2 & (item % i == 0)){
                    System.out.print(item + " ");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        int n1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int n2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int n3=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int n4=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int n5=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Prime ob=new Prime();
        ob.checkPrime(n1);
        ob.checkPrime(n1,n2);
        ob.checkPrime(n1,n2,n3);
        ob.checkPrime(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5);  
        Method[] methods=Prime.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
        boolean overload=false;
        for(int i=0;i<methods.length;i++)
        {
            if(set.contains(methods[i].getName()))
            {
                overload=true;
                break;
            }
            set.add(methods[i].getName());

        }
        if(overload)
        {
            throw new Exception("Overloading not allowed");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can't change *that* code, and `in` hasn't been declared, then unless you're able to change the superclass to add a variable there, you're stuck. That's a very odd requirement though. Why can't you just change that code to use `System.in`?

Comment: One line of code is not enough to answer that question. Where is `in` declared and is there a setter method for it are only two things that would be good to know.

Comment: I have provided more context; this is a new challenge but I just can't seem to find a way to make it work... I get errors that 'cannot find symbol' for 'in' (not declared). But how do I declare outside the class?

Comment: Can I declare that static field outside the class? If not, does that mean this challenge is impossible? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, when Oleg said that 'in' needs to be a static field, I realised that you can import **static** java.lang.System.*;  so that 'System.in' is replaced with 'in'.

Comment: Yes you can do that. I just finished writing a similar answer, though I used another class and your solution is simpler. I guess I was wrong and this is in fact possible. Was this a job interview question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static import.

Here's [Static Import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import) wiki link which explains the static import in Java with an example. 
Be careful while using static import as it might lead to ambiguity issues.

Comment: Please add some key details from the link to the answer above for the benefit of other users.